# Best Practice for Naming the Id Attribute of Dom Elements

Tags: asp.net, javascript, naming-conventions

This is related to naming conventions for a DOM element's id attribute and I guess the name attribute as well. When it comes to JavaScript, from what I understand and have done is always use camel case except for the names of classes. Classes are Pascal cased.

Having said that I develop in ASP.NET mainly and here's where I run into a naming issue for the id attribute. In ASP.NET if you drag and drop a new server control to a page(which I rarely do, I'm a type the markup kinda guy), the default names are always Pascal cased because they need to conform to the .NET framework naming guidelines for server-side code.

So when it comes to naming the id attribute of ASP.NET server controls or just elements in markup, I follow the rule to camel case the id attribute (Javascript naming guidelines), but this conflicts with the .NET naming guidelines.

So, one, what casing do you folks normally do for the id attribute in DOM elements and two what do the .NET folks who develop in ASP.NET do for naming the id attribute?

On top of that when I'm creating form elements in markup, I generally use Hungarian notation for text inputs, like

```
<input type="text" id="txtUserName" />
```

or for checkboxes like

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkSelectAll" />
```

Which definitely goes against .NET server-side code naming guidelines and maybe JavaScript guidelines as well.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Question seems like it probably belongs in "Community Wiki"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- Keep it semantic. Use complete, simple, (preferably English) words. Don't try to come up with something fancy or technical, and don't describe what it *is* - we know that. Describe what it *does*. Describing purpose adds informational value.
- Don't abbreviate anything! `BW_RCB01_SW` meant something to the team who did our CSS to years ago, but it doesn't mean anything to me now and I have to work backwards to try to translate what `BW_RCB01_SW` corresponds to for my purposes, and either remember that translation or document it somewhere. Better? `blackwhite-boxtype1-bottomleft`. It's longer but also doesn't require a Rosetta stone.
- Keep it all lower-case and use underscores or hyphens. I prefer hyphens, but that's totally a preference. There should be no impediment to using hyphens, since they are not reserved in CSS or HTML and IDs are treated as literal strings in every other language. Lower case is all experience - too many hours wasted wondering why the heck won't this style apply oh. `pageContainerLeft` is not the same as `pageContainerleft`.
- Identify *exactly* what that element is, but no more. Think seriously about each piece of information you're embedding in the name and whether it's necessary. In your example - do you *need* to know it's a checkbox by the ID? Unlikely. You already know what element you're referring to because it's a unique ID and you have to code against that element anyway.

Comment: Hey Rex, thanks for the comments. You can see my own comment above about slapping myself on the hand for Hungarian notation. I'm assuming that you generally respect the .NET naming guidelines but in the case of all lowercase à la hyphens or underscores for the id attribute you stray because of your many hours of lost productivity as you mention in point 3 of your post?

Comment: @nickyt in .NET I always follow proper casing for public & protected members and camel casing for private members.

Comment: @Rex I'm still a little confused or maybe I haven't had enough coffee this morning. You say "I always follow proper casing for public & protected members" but you're saying in point three of your answer in respect to the id attribute "all lower-case and use underscores or hyphens". I only mention this because part of my question was for .NET developers. ASP.NET server controls have the ID property that when rendered yields an HTML id attribute. And when you add controls to the page they are protected. So doesn't the all lower case contradicts public/protected Pascal Casing? Time 4 coffee...

Comment: @Nickyt sorry, I meant to say "when using .NET I follow..." regarding pure .NET code. As contrast to what I do for client-side, which is the lower-case and hyphens. I avoid using IDs for server-side controls like the plague, because they are controlled by ASP.NET and "username" gets transformed into ctl00_panel1_username". When dealing with server-side controls which I will need to manipulate in the client-side, I always use class names and jQuery.

Comment: using hyphens tends to break javascript as described here: http://hanuska.blogspot.com/2008/10/html-id-attribute-valid-values.html

Comment: @jgreep not really, because the usage described in that blog post is non-standard and should be avoided anyway.

Comment: As far as I can tell, to better separate css styles from `id's` (that can be used as a reference to the style as well, sure) is to use hyphens in css rules (`classes`) and underscore for `id` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Naming as few objects as possible definitely helps keep things clean. If you can get by naming the parent and just referring to the child, that's going to be better (in my opinion). You get the bonus of slightly less html rendered to the client  on each page.

For when I do have to name elements though, I prefer all lowercase, with underscore notation. I've been tricked up by not getting my case right in CSS files before, so if I can count that out as a problem early, that's as relief.

Underscores are characters while dashes can be interpreted as minus's, so that's one more potential problem - makes sense to stick with underscores only. Flex, for instance, doesn't accept XML with attributes named with dashes (i know these are values not attributes; but still a safe bet).

I agree with above though -- no element types or positioning or color as a class/id. Hungarian notation == bad. Very useful to determine what's an ID. I like naming form fields in a object specific ways - `user_login, user_email, user_address_state_id, user_address_country_id` etc, might all show up on a user registration form. Usually non-form fields aren't long enough for underscores, otherwise you might be able to rename them.

Answer (score 1):

One of the HTML gurus at my last job actually recommended delimiting multi-word IDs with dashes

```
<input type="text" id="user-name" />
```

I'm struggling to remember why - I don't have access to those internal standards documents anymore.  I know that really doesn't answer your question about Pascal vs Camel casing, though.

I'd personally advise against using HN - I find it to be a largely abhorrent practice.  What happens if you need to change your checkbox array to a select element instead?  Now the element's ID has false semantics baked-in.  It's just not worth the hassle, IMO.

Comment: Maybe he suggested dashes because all the properties use dashes to seperate words, such as 'text-align' , 'text-indent', etc

Comment: Yeah I know the Hungarian notation is bad. It just kind of stuck with me from the days when I used to code VB6. Funnily enough, I believe I only ever do it for textboxes/textareas and checkboxes. Regardless, it violates the .NET naming guidelines which I'm generally quite good about adhering to when it comes to server-side code.

Comment: maybe he couldn't be bothered holding down shift between words, hythens look nice too (imho)

Comment: A down vote? On this?  Really?  Come on, I've had answers worthy of a downvote, and this isn't one of them =/

Comment: Using dashes in ids stops you referring to them using dot notation in JS and forces you to use the more long-winded square bracket notation instead. I'd avoid this approach.

Comment: What?  Nodes aren't identified on the DOM by their ID - that's why we have document.getElementById(). I know IE exposes element IDs in the DOM tree, but that's not standard.  And even if your point was an issue, are you really insinuating that 3 extra characters is "long winded"?  Don't be daft.

Comment: As I mentioned in another comment, hyphens tend to break javascript: http://hanuska.blogspot.com/2008/10/html-id-attribute-valid-values.html

Comment: @jgreep - I dismiss that.  `document.idname` is non-standard and bad practice - use `document.getElementById()`.  And even if you did want to do it that way, bracket notation will still work (`document['id-name']`)

Comment: Is there any chance you've been able to track down why hyphenated-lowercase is recommended for HTML id's?

Comment: What I know is that Google SEO mandates hyphens instead of underscores to understand keywords. You can use the id of elements in the URL fragment, so I'm assuming hyphens are just that much better to use. If a plugin can't handle that, then you should stop using it.

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, but I've had problems with hyphens as names of id's and css class names when using certain javascript libraries. This is very rare, but you obviously want to avoid something like this. Because of this I use camel case or underscores. You can use underscores as well.

Otherwise the general rule is to have meaningful names that are easily read and understood. When it comes to "controls" make sure you follow some sort of a naming convention. Personally i prefer postfixes over prefixes (i.e. nameText instead of textName) but I try to avoid postfixes as I find them too verbose.

So:
 1. Meaningful names.
 2. Avoid post-/prefix.
 3. Avoid abbreviations (ie. address instead of addr).
 4. Take your time.

Comment: I agree.  Hyphens cause problems: http://hanuska.blogspot.com/2008/10/html-id-attribute-valid-values.html

Answer (score 1):

According to mozilla (best source for dom), best practice would be using alphabetic characters and using hyphens (if more than one word).

> although having your IDs somewhat human-readable can be useful for code comprehension, e.g. consider "ticket-18659" versus "r45tgfe-freds&$@"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Answer (score 0):

Here are some naming guidelines that have helped me out with my ids and classes in the DOM:

- don't include the type in the name (ie, no txt or chk). I can select that info using CSS or jQuery much more descriptivlely
- use underscores as separators in the name. Hyphens don't always work out in other languages, and camel casing is a little tough to read in markup